# UIActivityIndicatorView Not Appearing After Scrolling UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a table view controller and I display a UIActivityIndicatorView in the center of the screen in viewDidLoad()

```
let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds;
        let width = bounds.size.width
        let height = bounds.size.height

        loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(width / 2, height / 2, 75, 75))
        loadingIndicator.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        loadingIndicator.backgroundColor = kfbBlue
        loadingIndicator.center = CGPointMake(width / 2, height / 2 - 37)
        loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .WhiteLarge
        loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        self.tableView.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating()
```

This works just fine. I have a reload method for reloading the table view data. reload() works, but if I press the button that calls this method after I have scrolled the table view, the activity indicator does not appear. It only appears if the table view is scrolled up to the top.

```
func reload() {
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating()
        self.beginParsing()
    }
```

How can I get the activity indicator to appear in the center regardless of how far the table view has been scrolled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add the `UIActivityIndicatorView` to the `UITableView`.  Add it to the center pf the parent view that holds the `UITableView`.  You are adding it to the `UITableView`'s content view, which will scroll.  Add it outside that if you want it to persist even when the `UITableView` has been scrolled. Most likely something like this:

```
self.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
```

instead of your line

```
self.tableView.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
```

If you are using a `UITableViewController`, the topmost view will be the TableView, so you that won't work. You will instead have to adjust the center of the activity indicator to take into account the scroll location:

```
loadingIndicator.center = CGPointMake(width / 2, self.tableView.contentOffset.y + height / 2 - 37)
```

Comment: Is your `UIViewController` a `UITableViewController`, meaning self.view is the same as self.tableView?

Comment: It's a UITableViewController

Comment: So the topmost view is a TableView.  So you'll have to adjust the center of the UIActivityIndicatorView.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: I had to change this to tableView.contentOffset.y, but otherwise, it works. Thanks.

Comment: You are correct.  Coding in the text editor leads to mistakes. :)  I've updated the answer.